# The reason for me 'going' there or 'to go' there - which is correct?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Which one is grammatically correct?

> The reason for me going there is obvious
>
> The reason for me to go there is obvious.

My problem is not only with "reason+...." in particular.I'm also ambivalent as to  which formation I should use ,for example , take the word "motivation". ***The motivation for them to start this project*** ..or ***the motivation for them starting this project.***

Comment: Both of these are common usage. I'm not sure whether one is technically "more correct" than the other, but I doubt that most native speakers would be aware of a difference either. They have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

The correct structure is the one with to+infinitive:

> The reason for me to go there is obvious.

In order to make the first example acceptable, it should be altered like this:

> The reason for **my going** there is obvious.

Comment: I admit I'm kind of new to Stack Exchange, but I'd like to ask the reason for the downvote, if it's possible, so that I can improve my answer as well as my future posts. Thanks.